# Create app installation link to persist after installing app from appstore

Tags: android, ios, cordova, cordova-plugins

I want to create a shareable link to my app with an embedded token. Once the user clicks on the link, they should be taken to app/ play store and install the app. After installation I should be able to access the embedded token from the link. Is this possible?

Comment: This is not possible  on iOS

Comment: you can create a link that open the app if installed (and has an urlScheme), or go to the app store if it isn't installed. If the app is installed and opened from the link you'll get the token, but if it isn't installed and it's opened from the app store you won't get the token

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the [deep-linking](https://dev.branch.io/features/) implementation from branch.io. This feature allows to create links which persists even after the app installation and is provided by branch.io sdk. For documentation refer https://branch.io/how-branch-links-work/